# checkInterval configuration is enough or need to delete _jsp.class

Tags: jsp, tomcat

Am using Apache Tomcat 5.5.25.

I want JSP files which am going to update to take into effect (display updated content to User when that JSP is accessed) without restarting server.

I don't want to delete the files under _/org/apache/jsp.   But I want my updated JSP to reflect its updated contents.

Is it enough that I configure `web.xml` with `checkInterval` , `modificationTestInterval` & `development`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Tomcat 5.5, you could set `reloading` to **true** to only check if JSP pages have been modified.

But yeah, if you set `development` to **true** it's also fine, just greedier.

**See also:**

- [Jasper Configuration in Tomcat 5.5](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jasper-howto.html#Configuration)

Comment: So with this setup I don't have to delete files under `_/org/apache/jsp` ? And it will reflect the updated content automatically ?

Comment: Yeah, those files will be replaced by the updated ones. Try it, it's easy to find out! :)

Comment: There is no mention of `reloading` in web.xml file.  Whereas there is mention of other attributes like `checkInterval`, `development` etc...

Comment: Did you take a look at the link I gave you in the answer? It mentions **reloading**.